# Obtaining text from a user with one View Controller, Adding that value to the database and displaying it in another VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am new to programming so please bear with me.

The basic thing I am trying to achieve is as follows. Prompt the user for text in a ModalViewController, add that text to the database using Core Data and display that text in a TableViewController.

I have done some extensive work with this and I have the Core Data Model and entities already set up. The ModalViewController is a UITextFieldDelegate and it calls the appropriate textFieldDidEndEditing and I've set the self.delegate = self.

I've created a protocol in the ModalViewController which sends the text over to its presenting view controller. The Presenting View Controller calls that Delegate method and obtains the text. So this is where I'm stuck.

Using breakpoints and NSLog, I can see that when the presenting table view controller calls that delegate method, it HAS the right value; whatever I added into the Modal View Controller is that value. The NSLog shows it too.

From this delegate method, I call a useDocument method which basically does 3 if statements, checking whether the document is created, checking the state of the document and whether it is closed and checking whether the document has an opened state.

I have a NSManagedObjectSubClass to represent the "Person" entity, so in that class, using categories, I have a method called personWithName:`(NSString *)name inManagedObjectContext` and from the useDocument method, I call a transactionInDatabase method which in turn calls this.

The Person Category goes in and does the insertNewObjectForEntityForName. It goes foward and sets the value of person.name to = name (that was passed in).

The debugging shows that this works and the value of person.name (which is of course an attribute in the Person entity) gets set as the name, until the return "person" at the end of this method and suddenly the value is nil.

In the modal view controller, the "name" property is nonatomic, copy but I have tried strong and weak with the same effect.

Basically, I want the user to add text into the modal view controller and have that text added to the database so in the presenting view controller, when I call and do an NSFetchRequest into that entity, the result appears in a TableViewController.

I understand this is a fairly complex set up but at the same time, I can imagine this is also very common so any light shed on this would be massively appreciated.

Comment: just describe ur problem in short

Comment: Tell only what others may need to know to tell a solution. I am not getting any idea of what you are trying to do after reading the question.

Comment: Hi Manujmv, I want to obtain text from one view controller from the user, add that value to the core data database entity and display that value in another view controller which is a table view controller. I want to repeat that.

Comment: Thanks Harkrishnan - just added a comment - basically, obtain text from one VC from the user, add that value to the core data database and display that value in another VC doing a fetchrequest

Comment: This suffers from "TL;DR". Please edit it down to a succinct question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First You need to UnderStand Basics of CoreData, Viewcontrollers .

It is best try with this [This is all you want](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-to-core-data/).

Comment: Thanks Viruss mca, that is honestly exactly what I need. Thanks again.